# Is variable required instead of "or"

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Simple Hide Row not functioning when given multiple options

I've tried setting a Variable for the range and got same mismatch

```
If Range("J178") = "Credit" Or "Debit" Or "Both" Then
    Rows("180").Hidden = False
Else
    Rows("180").Hidden = True
End If
```

I expected the code to run or not; not the `Run time 13 type mismatch` I'm receiving.

Comment: You can't write `Range("J178") = "Credit" Or "Debit"`. You need to re-write `Range("J178") = "Credit" Or Range("J178") = "Debit"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1 - Write out each condition longhand (case sensitive)

```
If Range("J178") = "Credit" Or Range("J178") = "Debit" Or Range("J178") = "Both" Then
    Rows("180").Hidden = False
Else
    Rows("180").Hidden = True
End If
```

Option 2 - Check an array with the worksheet's Match (not case sensitive)

```
If IsNumeric(application.Match(Range("J178"), Array("Credit","Debit", "Both"), 0)) Then
    Rows("180").Hidden = False
Else
    Rows("180").Hidden = True
End If
```

Option 3 - Use a Select Case method (case sensitive)

```
Select Case Range("J178"),Value
    Case "Credit", "Debit", "Both"
        Rows("180").Hidden = False
    Case Else
        Rows("180").Hidden = True
End Select
```

Option 4 - Use a modified Select Case method (not case sensitive)

```
Select Case lcase(Range("J178"),Value)
    Case "credit", "debit", "both"
        Rows("180").Hidden = False
    Case Else
        Rows("180").Hidden = True
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

... Option 5 (following from @user10970498)

Dispense with the If-Then-Else-EndIf construct:

```
Rows("180").Hidden = (Range("J178") = "Credit" Or Range("J178") = "Debit" Or Range("J178") = "Both")
```

or

```
Rows("180").Hidden = IsNumeric(application.Match(Range("J178"), Array("Credit","Debit", "Both"), 0))
```

This works because the Hidden property is a `Boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter alternative using [`Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) :

```
Rows("180").Hidden = Not [or(J178 = "Credit", J178 = "Debit", J178 = "Both")]
```